# После добавления поля в dataset, access… при скроле

Tags: база-данных, delphi, windows-10, firebird, interbase

Делал программу с базой данных №1, в котором есть *dataset1* – master, *dataset2* - detail, привязанный к двум таблицам. Добавил в *dataset2*, новое поле «*name_pair*», типа *lookup*, для отображения в нем содержимого поля «*name*» в *dataset1*
Теперь при пролистывании dataset1, возникает:

> Access violation at address 004CC6F0 in module 'Meta.exe'. Read of address 00000014

причем, если сразу спозиционироваться на записи в *dataset1* в которой есть привязка в *dataset2* - все показывает, но при дальнейшей прокрутке - опять таже ошибка.

Мне так кажется, при ошибка летит тогда, когда в dataset2, есть данные, и придвигались к записи прокруткой.
При удалении поля «*name_pair*» - **ошибка пропадает**.

причем, если сразу спозиционироваться на записи в dataset1 в которой есть привязка в dataset2 - все показывает, но при дальнейшей прокрутке - опять таже ошибка.

Мне так кажется, при ошибка летит тогда, когда в dataset2, есть данные. 
При удалении поля «name_pair» - ошибка пропадает.

Решил создать чистый эксперемент, новое приложение, создал новую базу №2 (2 таблицы, несколько полей в каждой, завел несколько строк), два новых dataset, завязал их межу собой [image: введите сюда описание изображения], во второй dataset добавил новое поле (в общем все как и в основной программе) – таже самая ОШИБКА

Заранее спасибо.

Нашел как получается ошибка:
Если в Grid попадают все строки/данные (по высоте), то я могу свободно перемещаться вверх/вниз - ошибки НЕ будет.
Если же в Grid попадает НЕ все строки (по высоте), ТО ВЫЛЕТАЕТ ошибка...

P.S.
При установке галки "UseDebug DCUs" ("Options - Compiler"), во время этой ошибки меня выкидывает в модуль "...delphi7\source\vcl\IBCustomDataSet.pas" на строку №1847 (на "function TIBCustomDataSet.IsVisible(Buffer: PChar): Boolean;")... А в этом модуле я изменять ничего не хочу

Comment: У Вас нет никакого дополнительного написанного кода, может ошибка кроется там? И какая версия Delphi?

Comment: Ошибка по адресу с нулями, обычно, означает попытку доступа к переменной неинициализированного объекта.

Comment: Нет, кода нет никакого, кроме сгенерированных в *dataset* запросов

Comment: При установке галки "UseDebug DCUs" ("Options - Compiler"), во время этой ошибки меня выкидывает в модуль "...delphi7\source\vcl\IBCustomDataSet.pas"  на **строку №1847** (на "**function TIBCustomDataSet.IsVisible(Buffer: PChar): Boolean;**")... А в этом модуле я изменять ничего не хочу